# Re-initializing a Promise (Scala)

Tags: scala, functional-programming, promise

I've been fairly comfortable with the general notion of Promises from other languages (mainly Java and JavaScript) for a while now (possibly misguidedly so, I suppose), but when tinkering with the Promise API in Scala, I banged my head on a "style" problem I've not yet managed to resolve (no pun intended!), and to be fair, I don't know if I "should" resolve it.

My concern relates to use of promise/future to handle a repeating (e.g. event-like) situation. Here's the code (sorry it's kinda big considering the tiny part of it that matters, but I'm not sure how to discuss this clearly without a concrete example.

```
import javax.swing._
import scala.concurrent.Promise

object PromGui {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    var promise = Promise[String] // VAR?? really?
    promise
      .future
      .map(s => s"The initial value is $s")
      .foreach(Console.err.println)

    val f = new JFrame("My Frame")
    val p = new JPanel()
    val t = new JTextField()
    val b = new JButton("Press me!")
    p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS))
    f.setContentPane(p)
    p add t
    p add b

    b.addActionListener( e => {
      promise.success(t.getText)
      promise = Promise[String] // var because this needs to update it
      promise.future
        .map(s => s"The subsequent value is $s")
        .foreach(Console.err.println)
    })

    f.setSize(400, 200)
    f.setVisible(true)
  }
}
```

Now, the thing that bothers me is that "`var promise`" at the second line inside the main method. It seems to me that Promises/Futures are a somewhat "FP" kind of concept (the promise pipeline being a monadic-like thing and all, and the flatmap and variations being higher order functions). But I cannot for the life of me (and I might well be getting nicely set up for a good self-kicking if you show me how simple this really is) see how to get the promise to "reset" without creating a new one, and if I have to create a new one, I cannot see how to interact with it without using a mutable variable.

So, I guess the real question is, what's the elegant way to construct code that handles a cyclic type occurrence using promise/future?

EDIT:

I realize I represented this question poorly at the outset. I don't want to "re-trigger" the original Promise, I want to allow the conclusion of processing of a Promise to configure/setup a new one. That, of itself isn't hard, but I was hoping to find a structure that allowed me to do this without using a "var". It feels like there "ought" to be a construct that would let me create the new Promise, and therefore the reference to it, in something closure-like. But I'm not seeing it, and it seems others aren't either, so maybe this is just a dead end question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't uncomplete a `Promise` or a `Future`. You're probably looking for something like `Observable`, `Rx`, `Var`, ... from Scala.rx or RxScala.

Comment: I might misunderstand you, but I don't want to *un*complete it, I want  just want to be able to handle another button press (or more generally, to attach a promise pipeline configured identically to the original one, on the "same" triggering condition). The code I showed works perfectly, it's just the use of the mutable state that feels kinda ugly.

And while it might indeed be true that there's "a better API" this is actually a conceptual investigation of Promise/Future, not an exercise is solving a problem (though of course, the Rx thing is valuable as part of the discussion :)

Comment: Of course, if the essence of your comment is "Promise isn't meant for that" that would certainly be a useful contribution to my understanding of the concepts. Seems odd that this is the main entry in the "Programming in Scala" (third edition) book if it's that limited though.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. When you said reinitialize a `Promise` I took that as reuse the same `Promise`. But whatever the specifics, the `Promise` API is not meant for recurring events (although they can be built on top of it, like you did), while `Rx` is.

Comment: yeah, sorry, the uncertainty of terminology and the potential for confusion was was a big part of why I put concrete code in, to try to get past that. (though the possibility that I could have overlooked some kind of "reset" method had occurred to me too!)

I guess I have this feeling that there must be some way to "wrap a closure" around the whole "start again from the beginning" thing, such that the var can be replaced with a val. Haven't found it yet though!

Comment: I don't exclude the possibility that some solution with `Promise` but without a var exists.

Comment: @TobyEggitt, as Jasper said the `Promise` is a wrong tool for a `cyclic event` in any language. Design of the `Promise` is explicitly to handle single event and to block further state transitions (so it can't be "resolved" twice). This is the same in probably the most popular API in JS world as well: [Promise/A](https://promisesaplus.com/) (look at items `2.1.2.1` and `2.1.3.1`). Obviously if you use a wrong tool, you will have to struggle with it along the way. Use the right tool (some viable options are mentioned in the answer as well)!